# start chronometer from dialog box

Tags: dialog, box, chronometer

I would like my chronometer start when i click "ok" button from my Dialogbox... I can not. 
I only succeed to start my chronometer when dialog box open. Then when i click "ok" button time has passed...

Thanks for your help... I begin to code.

My code:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Chronometer;
    import android.widget.TextView;


public class ActivityOne extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Chronometer myChronometer;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timerlayout);

    myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    Button buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    Button buttonReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);


    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonReset.setOnClickListener(this);




final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActivityOne.this, R.style.dialogchrono);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogchrono);

dialog.setTitle("Titre");
TextView txt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
TextView txt1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView txt2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView txt3 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

txt1.setText("Texte1");
txt2.setText("Texte2");
txt3.setText("Texte3");
txt.setText("Texte");

    Button dismissButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        }
});
        dialog.show();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.startButton:
            myChronometer.start();
            break;
        case R.id.pauseButton:
            myChronometer.stop();
            break;
        case R.id.resetButton:
            myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    case R.id.startButton:
            myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            myChronometer.start();
            break;
```

You need to reset the Chronometer
Chronometer start counting when activity open